# How to find values that consists of a word for a JsonObject in a JsonObject using PyMongo

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

With the following JSON, how do I return products that have reviews consisting of a certain word (e.g. "good"). The data is stored in MongoDB and I am accessing it using PyMongo.

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64175a237438834b2397d676"
  },
  "productid": "B002PD61Y4",
  "product_name": "D-Link DWA-131 300 Mbps Wireless Nano USB Adapter (Black)",
  "actual_price": 19.64,
  "discount_percentage": 0.58,
  "product_desc": "Connects your computer to a high-speed wireless network",
  "rating_count": 8131,
  "rating": 4.1,
  "category": [
    "Accessories",
    "Computers",
    "NetworkAdapters",
    "NetworkingDevices",
    "WirelessUSBAdapters"
  ],
  "reviews": {
    "AGMG74N6WQGI376W7GEJJ4XD3ARQ": "Its not plug an play u need to install the driver and will support till 2.4 Ghz not above that",
    "AEHQQTEDMSXRGSBDDEIH3JF4AOMQ": "Good",
    "AGA2PZGWMQIRA46VYOTICFE7KCBA": "good tool to use for",
    "AHI2QJ4CLTCQWACDIC2LDFJPDAPA": "Brand is always good",
    "AETRIARSUFSMNG5LFJZMW6CBJMMQ": "Works well with cpplus dvr",
    "AEXAFY7V2ZRZI2GD2J6KDOWBZUBQ": "Overall good and a better experience",
    "AG7QMBEFFY2LJJKKEVWMJU2BMNRQ": "Surveillance Camera In My House",
    "AHAEBXTXQDY355AGFMFX3Z2VAAUQ": "It is useful to me."
  }
}
```

I have tried the following query but the returned items are empty.

```
# Find reviews with the value "great"
query = {"reviews": {"$elemMatch": {"$regex": "great", "$options": "i"}}}
results = collection.find(query)

# Print the matching documents
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

`$elemMatch` is for looking inside arrays, but your `reviews` is an object.
You can use `$objectToArray` to create an array of it:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$set: {rev: {"$objectToArray": "$reviews"}}},
  {$match: {"rev": {$elemMatch: {
        v: {
          "$regex": "good",
          "$options": "i"
        }
  }}}},
  {$unset: "rev"}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uEgtCkCB7Ui)

Comment: I ran the code on playground but there doesn't seem to be a change

Comment: A change from what? the playground returns the relevant document. Please add your expected result

Comment: it's working now, I just had to add the items with $ into quotes

Comment: How would I adjust the code to return reviews that consist of the given input rather than products? thank you

Comment: One option is something like [that](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CbsvUcNXzCA). It will be easier if you provide the requested output